# Move scopes from model to some module in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

There is some scope which are used in few models, and I want to move in module in order to to mix it. Is it possible? I use Rails 4, and tried to use the following code:

```
module ExistingScoping
    scope :existing, -> { ... }
end
```

But I've got error:

```
undefined method `scope' for ExistingScoping:Module
```

How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You'll probably want to look up [ActiveRecord::Concerns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html)

--

```
#app/models/concerns/existing_scoping.rb
module ExistingScoping
   extend ActiveSupport::Concern

   included do
     scope :existing, -> { ... }
   end
end

#app/models/model.rb
Class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
   include ExistingScoping
end
```

Comment: It looks like the right answer. Thanks!